# Wordpress plugin, $_POST is always empty

Tags: php, wordpress, post, plugins

I am creating plugin in Wordpress. I created subpage in Settings section.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_script_menu_page');

function my_script_menu_page(){
    add_options_page( 'Script', 'Script settings', 'manage_options', 'my_script', 'my_script_form');
}

add_action('admin_init', 'my_script_admin_settings');
function my_script_admin_settings(){
    register_setting('my_script_group', 'my_script_option');
}


function my_script_form(){

    var_dump($_POST);

    $options = get_option('my_script_option');

    ?>

    <form action="options.php" method="post">

        <?php settings_fields("my_script_group") ?>

        <p>
            <textarea name="my_script_option[my_script_id]"  rows="3" cols="100"><?php echo esc_attr( $options['my_script_id'] ); ?></textarea>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" class="button button-primary">
        </p>

    </form>


    <?php

}
```

How to check what is in $_POST? It is always empty array. What do I do wrong? $_GET is working fine. It returns page slug.

How to check if $_POST has anything in php? I want to add more actions if the button is pressed.

Comment: Open the developer console, go to the network tab, select `preserve log`, submit the form, select the request, go to the `headers` tab, and then view the `form data`.

Comment: How to check if $_POST has anything in php? I want to add more actions if the button is pressed.

Comment: you post to options.php, not to your plugin - which is why $_POST is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only do one mistake remove `action="options.php"` from form it will work.

Comment: You need to add your insert data code within this function.

Comment: Finally I did that. Thanks.